# Dialog becomes blur after applying animation

Tags: angularjs, animate.css

So I have built app with cordova. I am applying animations to pages using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css).

I have page which contain following html and includes ***support.html***

```html
<div id="home" class="my_cards" ng-init="init()">
    <div ng-include src="'app/shared/templates/headers.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include src="'app/shared/templates/spinner.html'"></div>

   <div class="main" ui-view="mainContent">
     <!-- some content here -->
    
    <div ng-include src="'app/shared/templates/support.html'"></div>

    <footer class="page-footer">
      <div class="row" style="width:100%; height:100%">
        <div class="col footer-col" ui-sref="home">
          <span class="icon ef-home"></span>
          <span>Home</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col footer-col" ui-sref="explore">
          <span class="icon ef-explore"></span>
          <span>Explore</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col footer-col current" ui-sref="mycards">
          <span class="icon ef-cards"></span>
          <span>My Cards</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col footer-col" ng-click="support()">
          <span class="icon ef-call"></span>
          <span>Call</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>

</div>
```

support.html

```html
<div id="supportModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content center-align">
        <div class="phone">+91 80 8066 8066</div>
        <div class="action row">
            <div class="col s6 m6 l6"><a ng-click="closeSupportModal()">Cancel</a></div>
            <div class="col s6 m6 l6"><a href="tel:+918080668066">Call</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The problem is when apply animation (marked red in image)**

[image]

**Dialog becomes blurred and the buttons on it don't work.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I just had to move support.html out of the parent `div id="home" class="my_cards" ng-init="init()">`.
and so the css and all changed accordingly.

I still did not understand why the problem occurred, explanation to this problem will be appreciated.